# look for some function on my sql to delete space

Tags: mysql

```
2-0003-80737-11-9
```

when we type  some character to mysql database some time I put space before 2 or after 9 (at the start and the end) how can i delete it on mysql I think it should be have some function on mysql to do this ( I try to search space delete on the web )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TRIM(' test ');
```

should work for you...

```
UPDATE table SET field = TRIM(field);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're after the [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function which removes both leading and trailing spaces from a string.